# What is the cause of the error "for/list: missing body expression after sequence binding..."?

Tags: racket

I get the error when I try this code:

```
(define odc (odbc-connect #:dsn DSNNAME #:user USER #:password PASSWORD)); 
(define-struct attendance-event (date flag)#:transparent)

(define-struct list-attendance-events (v)
    #:methods gen:stream
    [(define (stream-empty? stream)
       (empty? (list-attendance-events-v stream)))
     (define (stream-first stream)
       (first (list-attendance-events-v stream)))
     (define (stream-rest stream)
       (rest (list-attendance-events-v stream)))])

(define list-of-events (
(for/list ([(date code)
            (in-query odc "select date, code from attendance
where student_id = ? and term_code = ?
"12345" "654321")]))
(make-attendance-event date code)
```

I had the for/list working, but I changed something and broke it. I could get the 'first' element and I presume 'last', as well as check for empty?

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
(define list-of-events 
  (for/list ([(date code)
              (in-query odc "select date, code from attendance
                             where student_id = ? and term_code = ?"
                        "12345" "654321")])
    (make-attendance-event date code)))
```

Comment: Any way to make it easier to spot problems with parenthesis? Your code worked and I think what fixed is the parens.

Comment: I used `ctrl+i` in DrRacket to indent the code. The indentation looked off, which made me look at the pairings.

Comment: Also you had forgotten a ". The colors in DrRacket revealed that.

Comment: To code in a lisp you really need at least some basic editor support. DrRacket is ideal; or Emacs or Vim. But not a plain text editor. With a decent editor, you will type parens and hit a key to indent automatically. Just as @soegaard said, you'll start to catch paren problems from noticing that the indentation doesn't seem right.